# Referencing Array Constructor

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a method that creates an array:

```
public String[] ArrayMaker(){
    String[] arr;
    arr = new String[5];

    return arr;}
```

Now lets say I wanted to add an element to this newly created array, how would I reference it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String[] createdArray = ArrayMaker();
    createdArray[0] = "blah";
```

Also 
this is enought for your method:

```
public String[] ArrayMaker() { //name should be changed to arrayMakerLengthFive
    return new String[5];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code I would do as following:

```
String[] arr = ArrayMaker();
arr[0] = "Some input into index pos 0";
```

Also possible is:

```
String[] yourDesiredName = ArrayMaker();
yourDesiredName[0] = "Some input int index pos 0" ;
```

But beaware that the user of your ArrayMaker does not know the size. So

```
arr[5] = "Some input into index pos 0";
```

will fail.

Comment: Okay but lets say I dont know what the name of the created array will be?

Comment: What do you mean you do not know the name of the array? You can define the name as you like: See changes..

Comment: The name is the one you want.
You can do:

`String[] test = ArrayMaker();`

or you can do:
`String[] whatYouWant = ArrayMaker()`

The name you are using in the ArrayMaker method means something only inside that method. It returns an array of Strings and you can reference it with the variable name you prefer outside the ArrayMaker method.

Comment: Your question said, "How would I reference it"? Can you clarify what you actually want to do?

Comment: an array is made....(I dont know its name, but i know it was made using the arraymaker function) I want to create a method called "add" that will add an object to this array when called.

Comment: `But beaware that the user of your ArrayMaker does not know the size.` ... yes he does: `arr.length`.

Comment: Tom you are right... of course he knows IF and IF HE checks.. but he has no indication of how big the Array is he will get.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to go throught the array like this:

```
public class TestArray {

    public String[] ArrayMaker(){
        String[] arr;
        arr = new String[5];

        return arr;}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestArray ta = new TestArray();

        String[] newArray = ta.ArrayMaker();

        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = "some String";
        }

        for (String s : newArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

}
```